# Combine JSON files and recalculate percentages with JQ

Tags: arrays, json, bash, unix, jq

I'm using `jq` inside a bash shell script to process a list of JSON files daily, which combines them into a new array. After I combine them I need to recalculate values based on the value of each object within the array. This new JSON file is then consumed in a client-facing analytics HTML report.

I'm so close to getting it working, but can't figure out how to combine my below `jq` filters.

I can create an array of the recalculated percents in **Filter A**, and I can output the array I'm expecting (minus the new percent values) in **Filter B** but can't find a way to combine these into a **Filter C**.

**JQ Playground URL:** https://jqplay.org/#

[**JSON input (located on gist.github)**](https://gist.github.com/skplunkerin/f14ef7d4f6e8ecfc16408fa44747d8f1#file-1-input-json)

**Filter A:**

```
{"hits_percents": [(.[].hits.count / (group_by(.hits.count) | map(map(.hits.count))|add|add)*100)], "visitors_percents": [(.[].visitors.count / (group_by(.visitors.count) | map(map(.visitors.count))|add|add)*100)], "bytes_percents": [(.[].bytes.count / (group_by(.bytes.count) | map(map(.bytes.count))|add|add)*100)]}
```

**Output A:**

```
{
  "hits_percents": [
    1.2345679012345678,
    8.641975308641975,
    8.641975308641975,
    9.876543209876543,
    6.172839506172839,
    3.7037037037037033,
    1.2345679012345678,
    2.4691358024691357,
    58.0246913580247
  ],
  "visitors_percents": [
    4,
    28.000000000000004,
    28.000000000000004,
    8,
    4,
    8,
    4,
    8,
    8
  ],
  "bytes_percents": [
    0.31110007608374707,
    36.59886623706793,
    31.692110521802018,
    7.187835244744665,
    1.6285539319606,
    5.880482040688714,
    0.7481999111612437,
    0.6484148671259253,
    15.304437169365146
  ]
}
```

**Filter B:**

```
[.[] | { "hits": {"count": .hits.count, "percent": "TODO" }, "visitors": { "count": .visitors.count, "percent": "TODO"}, "bytes": {"count": .bytes.count, "percent": "TODO"}, "data": .data }]
```

[**Output B (located on gist)**](https://gist.github.com/skplunkerin/f14ef7d4f6e8ecfc16408fa44747d8f1#file-2-unwanted-output-json)

**Filter C:** (Filter A + B)

```
????
```

[**Desired Output C**](https://gist.github.com/skplunkerin/f14ef7d4f6e8ecfc16408fa44747d8f1#file-3-expected-output-json)

Any suggestions on how I can get the **Output C** within a bash script using `jq` would be fantastic. I've been turning my gears for several hours and currently out of ideas.

---

**Bonus Question:** How can I get `jq` to round up 2 digits on the percents?

I can't get any kind of math working, and their [Math documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Math) is too vague to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of your intermediate results "A" and "B" (denoted below by $a and $b), the following filter produces the required answer. The key is `transpose`:

```
($a | [.hits_percents, .visitors_percents, .bytes_percents] | transpose)
| . as $v
| reduce range(0; length) as $i
    ($b;
       .[$i].hits.percent = $v[$i][0] 
     | .[$i].visitors.percent = $v[$i][1]
     | .[$i].bytes.percent = $v[$i][2] )
```

There is probably a better way to get the final result, but you asked how the two intermediate results can be combined....

#### Bonus question:

```
 # Round a (positive) percentage to two decimal places:
 def percent:
   ((1000 * .) | floor)
   | (. % 10) as $r
   | ((. / 10) | floor) as $answer
   | if $r > 4 then ($answer + 1) else $answer end
   | . / 100
   ;
```

This could be used by adding `map(map(percent))` after the transposition:

```
def percent:
  ((1000 * .) | floor)
  | (. % 10) as $r
  | ((. / 10) | floor) as $answer
  | if $r > 4 then ($answer + 1) else $answer end
  | . / 100;
($a | [.hits_percents, .visitors_percents, .bytes_percents] | transpose)
  | map(map(percent))
  | . as $v
  | reduce range(0; length) as $i
      ($b;
         .[$i].hits.percent = $v[$i][0] 
       | .[$i].visitors.percent = $v[$i][1]
       | .[$i].bytes.percent = $v[$i][2] )
```

Comment: Awesome, this looks promising @peak! I've been trying to get it working for about an hour and keep getting `error: transpose is not defined`. Any ideas what could cause that? (I'm doing this in bash instead of the `jq play` website cause I couldn't get it working on that site either)

Comment: `transpose` was included as a builtin with jq 1.5.  If you cannot get a version of jq with `transpose` then you can paste in its definition. e.g. from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq

Comment: that makes sense, I'm using jq v1.3. I'll update and give it another try. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: I got v1.5 installed, and after lots of trial and error I cannot get this to work locally in my `bash` nor on the `jq play` site. I'll full on blame myself for not knowing how to implement your solution. Could you provide a little more information on how I'm suppose to use your answer to create the `jq '...'` command line output (to either work on `jq play` or in my `bash`)?

Comment: First, I'd forget about sponge for the time being.  Second, I'd suggest putting the "A output" into a file named (something like) a.json, and the "B output" into a file named (e.g.) b.json, and then invoking jq as follows: jq -n --argfile a a.json --argfile b b.json -f command.jq # where command.jq contains the program as given above.

Comment: BAM, got it to work, thanks for helping me @peak! Did this: `jq -n --argfile a temp-a.json --argfile b temp-b.json 'command.jq'`. I needed to remove the suggested `-f` as well as surround the command with single `'`ticks. Mind if I edit your answer to show that command line?

Comment: @skplunkerin - I don't know what's in your command.jq but it is evidently not what I intended; also, your remark about the single-tick quotation marks suggests that there's something strange going on. So I'd suggest leaving things as they are until the fog has been lifted.

Comment: I have a bash script that is running this command, that's why I'm not calling an external `command.jq` file, hense my "single ticks" (where the logic you suggested is being run in the same line).

Comment: My jq is pretty basic, can you explain how this works?

Comment: @smci - I'd suggest starting with one of the tutorials (see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#tutorials), and then reading up on map, reduce, and transpose.  Using `debug` often helps :-)

Comment: @peak I already read several tutorials, I'm trying to understand what does the paradigm you use `. as $v ... .[$i].var.percent = $v[$i][0]` do exactly, does it declare three temporary arrays and actually store into them (wasteful?), or just infer an iterator? Also how does your `percent()` function work?

Comment: @peak I already read several tutorials, I'm trying to understand what does the paradigm you use `. as $v ... .[$i].var.percent = $v[$i][0]` do exactly, does it declare three temporary arrays and actually store into them (wasteful and non-scalable?), or just infer an iterator? Also how does your first percent() function work?